# simple button widget size different on different screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a Simple widget of one row and one column.  It has only one button. It works fine on my mobile device but on other devices with smaller width than mine, it becomes two rows and two column.

According to the formula `(n*74)-2` its max width and height is 72 72dp.  How can I  keep widget a single row and column on all devices?

```
android:minWidth="72dp" 
android:minHeight="72dp"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:minWidth="72dp" android:minHeight="72dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="0" android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout" > </appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @dimen to handle values for different screen sizes.  Create a dimens.xml in each of the folders for the screen sizes and create an item to hold a value for the widget size.

```
res/values-xlarge 
<dimen name="widget_min">196dp</dimen> 
res/values-large 
<dimen name="widget_min">144dp</dimen> 
res/values-normal 
<dimen name="widget_min">96dp</dimen> 
res/values-small 
<dimen name="widget_min">72dp</dimen>
```

Then, in your layout file use "@dimen/widget_min" in place of a hardcoded value.
android:minWidth="@dimen/widget_min"